# Oracle-Should I use temp table or ref cursor

Tags: database, oracle, join

I have the following scenario for which i will have to write a stored procedure:

1. Header table containing invoice_ID and invoice_line_ID
2. Address Line table containing invoice_line_id and 'Ship_From' and 'Ship_To' corresponding to each invoice_line_ID in header table.
   3.Address header table containing invoice_ID and 'Ship_From' and 'Ship_To' corresponding to each invoice_id in header table.

The cases are such that not always all 'Ship_From' and 'Ship_To' information will be present in the Address Line table. In that case the information needs to be selected from Address Header table.

So i will write a case structure and two joins : 1. That will join Header table and Address Line table
2. That will join Header table and Address Header table.
with the condition to do the second join in case entire information for a particular invoice_line_id is not available in line table.

My question here is where should i store the information? I will use a cursor to perform the above case structure. But should i use a ref cursor or a temp table in this case?

Please note that my customer is not liking the idea of extra database objects in the database so i might have to delete the temp table after i am done displaying. I need help on that as well as to is there any alternative to temp table or whether ref cursor take up extra space on the database or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case you shouldn't use temporary tables. This sort of tables not differs much from ordinary tables. It is an object, that persists in DB always. If you want to create and drop it every time, you need to solve a number of problems. If two users work with a database in a same time, you need to check, is it already created by another user or not. Or you need to be sure, that every user will create a table with unique name. You need a mechanism to delete a table, that was not deleted properly, for example, when user session was aborted due to network problem. And many other problems. It is not a way to use oracle temporary tables.

**UPD**

About refcursors.

```
declare
  my_cursor sys_refcursor;
  num number;
begin
  open my_cursor for select rownum from dual;

  loop
    fetch my_cursor into num;
    exit when my_cursor%notfound;
    -- do something else
  end loop;
end;
/
```

This is a simple example of using cursors. As for me, it matches more in your situation than temporary table.

Comment: Is ref cursor same as temp table?is there a way to insert records in a ref cursor like i would do in a temp table?

Comment: You don't insert records to refcursor - you select them. This is main difference. Data in refcursor always located in memory. Refcursor itself is just some lines of code in a package, and during code execution it is a link on memory segment.

Comment: So in this case it has to be temp table because there is no other way of putting the records together if i have to loop through each and every line_id to check the info in each of the header and line address tables, can you suggest any other database object that i can use here?

Comment: I updated my answer. There is a number of database objects, that you can use: views, materialized views, cursors, temporary tables, ordinary tables. As for me, I would like to choose cursors or views in your place.